# Application to generate graphs from MySQL table

Tags: windows, mysql, charts

I am looking for a solution to generate graphs from MySQL tables (local MySQL server).

I would like it to work on Windows, and not be based on a server (like a PHP server). This is just basic stuff: extract the content of the table and generate a graph from that (the table has 2 columns).

I have tried Excel to do that, but it requires installing a plugin to support the MySQL connection, and the configuration is not really straightforward so it's not really fitting. The thing is a whole team will install the application, so I'm looking for the most straightforward solution.

Additionnaly, I've tried using cygwin and GNU plot, but it also requires installing plot through the cygwin installer... Not very simple. I'm just looking for an application (or a script) that can do it easily without extended configuration and installing dependencies.

**Edit: To sum up, I am looking for the minimal setup process**

Comment: You do realize that the most minimal setup is using a web server.  The client types in the URL and bang there it is.  Maybe you add a user/pass to control access.  Yes, you do have to setup a server, but only 1 time by 1 person.  You can't get simpler than that.

Comment: @cybernard you do realize this question is 8 years old. And actually there is a simpler solution to this question than what you think: https://www.metabase.com Just download it and run it, "it can't get simpler than that" (you missed the point of "who is going to use it"). I'll add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 years later, I would recommend [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) for these use cases.

It's simple to setup for a local usage:

- download
- open the app
- configure your database
- plot your graphs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at iReport (Open Source). It takes a bit of setup but the results are worth it.

http://jasperforge.org/project/ireport

*"iReport is the free, open source report designer for JasperReports. Create very sophisticated layouts containing charts, images, subreports, crosstabs and much more. Access your data through JDBC, TableModels, JavaBeans, XML, Hibernate, CSV, and custom sources. Then publish your reports as PDF, RTF, XML, XLS, CSV, HTML, XHTML, text, DOCX, or OpenOffice."*

Comment: I'm looking for the minimal setup process. I'm going to emphasise about that in the question.